# English equivalent for the Aramaic idiom "eyes so jealous they cannot carry"

Tags: expressions, idioms, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

That isn't a literal translation, but it's essentially similar.

When someone is jealous of you or your success and are resentful about it, in response we say "*their eyes cannot carry*"; Which means your success (or anything positive about you) is too heavy for their weak jealous eyes to bear or sustain, so their eyes cannot "*carry*" your success.

Sounds funny in English, but I wonder if there is an equivalent idiom. Thanks.

Comment: You could just replace “carry” with “bear it”.

Comment: Perhaps. But in my language, we literally mean that our success is so heavy, their jealous eyes cannot physically "carry" it.

Comment: "Bear" means "carry", so it would seem like a reasonable correspondence to the Aramaic idiom, even though in English we would not mention the eyes.

Comment: The verb "carry" needs an object so, "*There is so much jealousy **their eyes cannot carry it***"

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the Aramaic idiom, but if "carry" conveys the notion of denigrating the target of the jealousy, even if it is just mentally, consider the term **sour grapes**. It goes beyond the feeling of envy.

For example, suppose Tom got a job that includes overseas travel, and Jerry enjoys overseas travel but didn't get the job. If Jerry tells Tom that the job isn't all that good because he'll probably have to do lots of covid isolation, Tom can call Jerry's attitude "sour grapes".

> Sour grapes is the expression we use when someone puts something down in a negative way or makes it out to be unimportant solely because it is unattainable to them. Oftentimes the term is used to signify resentment.
> [-vinepair.com](https://vinepair.com/articles/term-sour-grapes-come/#:%7E:text=Sour%20grapes%20much%3F%E2%80%9D%20Sour%20grapes,is%20used%20to%20signify%20resentment.)

> Sour grapes describes the act of belittling something that you can not have, to make disparaging comments concerning an item that you can not afford or a job position that has been denied you, etc. Someone who makes remarks about something that are interpreted as sour grapes actually desires that thing, and downplays its importance because he can not have it.
> [-grammarist.com](https://grammarist.com/idiom/sour-grapes/)

Comment: I believe this entry somewhat comes close. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the English equivalent is:

> [be green with envy](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be-green-with-envy) ​
>
> - *to feel very unhappy because you wish you had something that someone else has*.

(McMillan Dictionary)